# Создание QLabel при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpushbutton, qlabel

У меня есть **QButtonGroup**, со 100 **QPushButton** при нажатии на которых, запускается функция, получающая координаты нажатой кнопки, на которых должен создаться **QLabel**, но этого не происходит по непонятным мне причинам.

**Код создания точки:**

```
    # Создание точки попадания
def create_dot(self, x, y):
    # Размер точки
    size = 10

    # Создание точки
    dot = QLabel(self)

    # Нормализируем координаты для точки
    x = self.normal(x, False) + self.half_square - (size / 2) + 1
    y = self.normal(y, False) + self.half_square - (size / 2) + 1

    print(x, y)

    dot.setGeometry(x, y, size, size)
    dot.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

    # Цвет и скругление углов точки
    dot.setStyleSheet(f'background-color: rgb(255,100,100); border-radius: {size / 2}px')  # Цвет букв
```

**Код создания кнопок:**

```
    # Создание кнопок для игрового поля
def create_buttons(self):
    for vertical_cord in range(0, 10):  # ПОТОМ ГОРИЗОНТАЛЬНАЯ ЛИНИЯ ИЗ КНОПОК РАЗМНОЖАЕТСЯ НА ВСЁ ПОЛЕ
        for horizontal_cord in range(0, 10):  # СНАЧАЛА СОЗДАЕТСЯ ГОРИЗОНТАЛЬНЫХ ЛИНИЯ ИЗ КНОПОК
            # Координаты по оси X
            x = self.normal(horizontal_cord, False) + self.half_square - (self.square / 2) + 1
            # Координаты по оси Y
            y = (self.square + 1) + (self.square * vertical_cord)

            btn = QPushButton(self)  # Создание кнопки
            btn.setGeometry(x, y, self.square, self.square)  # Установка размера и положения на поле
            btn.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)')  # Сделать все кнопки невидимыми, но рабочими
            self.btn_group.addButton(btn)  # Добавление в группу кнопок

    # Подключение кнопки к функции нажатия
    self.btn_group.buttonClicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
```

**Код при нажатии на кнопку:**

```
    # Обработка нажатий на кнопку
# clicked_btn - Нажатая кнопка
def button_clicked(self, clicked_btn):
    clicked_btn_x = clicked_btn.x() - 1  # Координаты X нажатой кнопки
    clicked_btn_y = clicked_btn.y() - 1  # Координаты Y нажатой кнопки

    x = self.normal(clicked_btn_x, True)  # Нормализированные координаты кнопки
    y = self.normal(clicked_btn_y, True)  # Нормализированные координаты кнопки

    self.create_dot(x, y)
```

**Нажатие считывается, координаты получаю, но QLabel не создаётся.**

**Странно, но при вызове функции `self.create_dot(x, y)` в любом другом месте, точка появляется.**

**Вот как должно выглядеть поле, если я нажму на первую кнопку:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: https://youtu.be/hT-Gwqy45XE

На видео я показал, что функция создания точки работает, если я запускаю её при запуске приложения, но не работает при нажатии на кнопку, хотя координаты кнопки я получаю

Comment: Если вам действительно нужна помощь, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была найдена. **QLabel** изначально создавался с атрибутом `setVisible(False)`.

При создании нужно было указать `setVisible(True)`

**Вопрос закрыт.**